# How to write a replacement for a build-in prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, prototype

I'm using a Javascript interpreter which seems to provide a buggy `Array.prototype.sort` and I'd like to replace it (at least for test purposes).

I've got a function `mySort(array, comparator)`, but how can I make it to a function working like `array.sort(comparator)`?

I also need to provide a default comparator, does a simple `return a<b ? -1 : a>b ? +1 : 0` suffice?

And there may be more problems I'm unaware of?

A side question: My simple sorting works, but I'd gladly replace it by some well tested code.

Comment: You can override default prototype but it's a bad idea in this case

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.prototype.sort=function(comp){ return mySort(this,comp);};
```

Or using custom arrays:

```
myArray=Object.create(Array.prototype);
myArray.sort=function(comp){ return mySort(this,comp);};

example=Object.create(myArray);
example.push(1,2);
example.sort();
```

Comment: Thank you. That simple? ;) No custom array, the sort function is probably broken (and even if it's not, I need to replace it in order to find out what's going on). +++ What about the default comparator?

Comment: @maaartinus: and you should consider that nothing can beat engine based ( in a native language like c ) code concerning performance...